# PowerShell script to add user to different domain in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to add users from a csv file who are from `domain1` to a security group in `domain2` using the following script.

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\test.csv" | ForEach-Object {Add-ADGroupMember -Server domain1.company.com -Identity "testSecurityGroup" -Members $_.'userName'}
```

But because the users are on a different domain than the security group, I'm getting this error message below. It cannot find the security group I want under the `domain1.company.com` domain that I wrote in my script.

Here's the error message:

```
Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'testSecurityGroup' under: 'DC=domain1,DC=company,DC=com'.
```

Comment: I believe it is actually saying that it cannot find a group called "testSecurityGroup” on the server/domain "domain1.company.com", not anything to do with the user being in one domain or the other.

Comment: Does `Get-ADGroupMember -Server domain1.company.com -Identity “testSecurityGroup”` work?

Comment: I have to ask, do you have a trust set up between the user's domain and the group's domain?

Comment: As aside, better not use those curly quote thingies in code, because they can result in unexpected behavior. In code, always use straight ones. Why do you quote `username` ?

Comment: Firstly, the AD trust need to be  set up between the two domains. 
Try the below command :
Import-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\test.csv" | ForEach-Object {Add-ADGroupMember -Server domain2.company.com -Identity "testSecurityGroup" -Members $_.'userName'}

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add the users from Domain1 to a security group in Domain2, but the below script tries to add the users to a security group in Domain1 which does not exist.

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\test.csv" | ForEach-Object {Add-ADGroupMember -Server domain1.company.com -Identity "testSecurityGroup" -Members $_.'userName'}
```

So, you get the below error :

```
Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'testSecurityGroup' under: 'DC=domain1,DC=company,DC=com'.
```

Instead, you can use the below command to add the users in Domain 1 to a security group in Domain2

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\test.csv" | ForEach-Object {Add-ADGroupMember -Server domain2.company.com -Identity "testSecurityGroup" -Members $_.'userName'}
```